# showmount gives following error on MAC

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, nfs

I am trying to mount on macOS the files that I have shared on my raspberrypi using NFS. But when I do `showmount -e rpiAddress` .It gives the following error.

```
showmount: Cannot retrieve info from host: kirtanpi: RPC failed:: RPC: Unable to send; errno = Bad file descriptor
```

The steps I followed on raspberrypi are as follows.

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common nfs-server -y
sudo mkdir /mnt/nfsserver
sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/nfsserver
```

This is my `/etc/exports` file.

```
/mnt/nfsserver 192.168.1.34 *(rw,sync)
```

and finally

```
sudo exportfs
```

Comment: did you try this ? http://superuser.com/questions/394767/nfs-lion-connection-is-not-working

Comment: I did ... not working